# How to change field type from dict to ReferenceField

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have two documents defined like this:

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, IntField, DictField

class PetModel(Document):
    name = StringField()
    age = IntField()

class PersonModel(Document):
    name = StringField()
    pet = DictField()
```

Is there a way to change the pet field type to ReferenceField if I already created PersonModel objects?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a migration script, easiest is probably to:

- collect all PetModel and build a mapping {pet_id: pet_dict}
- loop over the PersonModel documents using pymongo (the driver used by Mongoengine) and convert the `pet` field from DBRef to dict using the mapping built above
- save/update that document

MongoEngine has a page explaining some migration use case: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/migration.html#documents-migration